# How to store the Live Time in Json File using Node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I'm new in node js, when I create the Countdown Clock, Using With Nodejs and javascript,

I'm facing an issue with When the server restarted The Timer also Restarted

[image]

JSON File Using

```
StartTime.json 

    "UserTime": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Jack",
                "TimeDuration": 25:00
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Mike",
                "TimeDuration": 30:00
            }
    ]
```

StartTime -> 30:00 mins, ReminingLiveTime->24:52;

After Restarting I need the Same ReminingLiveTime to be stored on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood Your Question, Initially you Just Create Custom Api, Before Restarting The Server Pass the Time On it